# Solr 5.2.1 Access denied when trying to startup through powershell

Tags: powershell, solr

I have Solr version 5.2.1 normally it starts up fine with no issues, this morning I attempted to start Solr and I got the following issue:

```
Starting Solr on port 8983 from C:\solr-5.2.1\solr-5.2.1\solr-5.2.1\server

Access is denied.
Access is denied.

Direct your Web browser to http://localhost:8983/solr to visit the Solr Admin UI
```

I restarted the computer yet I still get this access denied issue, which I have not encountered before does anyone have the insight into why this is happening? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that full control windows permissions were required to be set for the directory Solr was in.

Answer (score 0):

Just update java version to [java 8](http://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-8-jdk-8-ubuntu-via-ppa/)

Run command:

> sudo bin/solr start

For example:

> Vostro-3550:/opt/solr-6.0.0$ sudo bin/solr start

Then Open Browser and the past:
http://localhost:8983/solr/