# starting solr when computer starts

Tags: powershell, solr

I am trying to get Solr to automatically start when I start my computer.
I have followed [how to run PowerShell Script when computer starts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20575257/how-to-run-powershell-script-when-computer-starts) with a script that starts Solr. When I run the script it starts Solr, but when I log on and log off, I get the error, "Access is denied", in my StartupLog.
I have followed [Solr 5.2.1 Access denied when trying to startup through powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32347052/solr-5-2-1-access-denied-when-trying-to-startup-through-powershell) and made sure that all permission are allowed for Solr but still get the same error.